# Regex for minium integer of 25

Tags: regex

I need a regex for an integer starting from 25 with no limit I tried:

```
^([2-9]\d[0-9]\d{2,})$
```

but I need it to start from 25 not 20 and I'm not even sure if this works correctly.

Comment: Why don't you convert it to an int and check that?

Comment: Why not just `$x >= 25`?

Comment: This is something you should use a simple `if` statement for, in your chosen language.

Comment: This is one of those cases where solving a problem with a regular expression leaves you with two problems.  Regexes are not the Sonic Screwdriver of programming.

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of validation you should be doing after parsing the value out. Just use a regex to get the integer.

Comment: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

Comment: Well, the OP might be using some kind of framework where all (s)he has is a pattern to validate a field. Regular expressions are not only used in full-fledged programming languages. But that brings up a far more important question. @user1863815, which tool or programming language are you trying to do this with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a regex that is slightly more concise than some of the others:

```
^(?!(1\d|2[0-4])$)[1-9]\d+$
```

You can test it here: http://www.rubular.com/r/PGdbtGYsWD

The approach is to just match `[1-9]\d+`, which will be a two or more digit number, and use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the beginning to prevent matches for any numbers between 10 and 24.

If leading zeros should be allowed, just add `0*` directly after the `^`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex

```
^([2-9]\d[0-9]\d{2,})$
```

Will match any number starting with `2-9` and having 5 digits or more (`\d`, `[0-9]` contribute one digit each, `\d{2,}` is for another two or more digits). You want something like this:

```
^0*(1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|2[5-9]|[3-9]\d)\d*$
```

As you can see this is rather ugly. If you are using some kind of programming languages, you should rather assert that it is a number (`^\d*$`) and check the range without regex.

But how does my regex work?

First we consume leading `0`s because they don't change the value of the number. And then we have an alternation depending on the first digit(s) of the number. If it's a `1` we know we need at least two more digits for it to be greater than `25`. If it's a `2` and the second digit is between `0` and `4` we also need another digit. If it's `25` or starts with `3` to `9`, two digits suffice. And after the alternation, we just allow arbitrarily many more digits.

[Working demo.](http://regexr.com?32vu1)

Answer (score 0):

Test it [here](http://regexr.com?32vtu)

```
^(2[5-9]([0-9])*|[3-9][0-9]+|[1-2][0-9]{2,})$
```

Comment: It appears to be correct now, but the unwieldiness and lack of clarity is a very good argument for what we're discussing in the comments on the OP - this is the wrong solution to the problem, even if it works. This validation should be done *after* retrieving the integer value.

Comment: @Kiyura: I don't think this is very unclear. He splits it up into three cases based on the first two numbers, and then determines that if they form something less than 25, there have to be some more numbers following them. A short comment which says just this would suffice in the code, I think. (And you cannot presuppose that you can do integer math in all applications where you can have regexes. What if this is a `grep` query?)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex to check the complement of that: (Eliminate anything that doesn't qualify: i.e match any thing that is less than 25)

- Not anything that starts with `-` (negative)
- Not anything that:

  - Starts with `[0-2]`, and
  - Is followed by `[0-4]`, and
  - Is not followed by another digit (If it is followed by another digit, then you have `> 200`)
- Not anything that includes a non-numeric character

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern

```
^(2[5-9]|[3-9]\d|(?!0)\d{3,})$
```

or (if you want to allow leading zeros)

```
^0*(2[5-9]|[3-9]\d|(?!0)\d{3,})$
```